# Why is simple XOR not working in Perl?

Tags: perl, xor

```perl
my $list = "1 3";
my @arr  = split " ", $list;
my $c    = $arr[0] ^ $arr[1];
print $c, "\n";
```

The above is giving an abnormal character.

It should give answer as 2, since 1 XOR 3 is 2.

Comment: You're splitting your array into `@arr` but then trying to manipulate `$c1`, `$c2`, `$c`. That's not going to work. Also, you're trying to do bitwise operations on strings. You're trying to XOR the string "1" rather than the number 1.

Answer (score 11):

[*The effect of `use feature qw( bitwise );` and similar (e.g. `use v5.28;`) is not covered by this answer as it didn't exist at time of writing.*]

`^` considers the internal storage format of its operand to determine what action to perform.

```
>perl -Mv5.14 -e"say( 1^3 )"
2

>perl -Mv5.14 -e"say( '1'^'3' )"
☻
```

The latter xors each character of the strings.

```
>perl -Mv5.14 -e"say( chr( ord('1')^ord('3') ) )"
☻
```

You can force numification by adding zero.

```
>perl -Mv5.14 -e"@a = split(' ', '1 3'); say( (0+$a[0])^(0+$a[1]) )"
2

>perl -Mv5.14 -e"@a = map 0+$_, split(' ', '1 3'); say( $a[0]^$a[1] )"
2
```

Technically, you only need to make one of the operands numeric.

```
>perl -Mv5.14 -e"@a = split(' ', '1 3'); say( (0+$a[0])^$a[1] )"
2

>perl -Mv5.14 -e"@a = split(' ', '1 3'); say( $a[0]^(0+$a[1]) )"
2
```

Comment: Is there any particular advantage to implict casting by performing an arithmetic op as opposed to explicitly with e.g. `int()`?

Comment: @Sobrique, They're both explicitly used math operations which are implicitly used to return a number. `0+$_` is more general purpose —it works for all numbers— while `int($_)` only works for integers (which is sufficient in this case).

Comment: @Sobrique, In addition to working in more circumstances, `0+` the symbol for numification used by overload.pm, and it parallels `"".` for stringification.

Comment: you only have to numify one of the operands for it to be a numeric xor

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer above, you've helped me learn some more about -E, as the example
`>perl -E"say( '1'^'3' )"` 
`☻`  above doesn't print the same value any more - seems to have to do with -E and use feature.
`$ perl -lE "print ord('1'^'3');no feature;print  ord('1'^'3');"` 
`50` 
`2`
Ah, it is the bitwise feature that does this
`perl -lE "print ord('1'^'3');no feature bitwise;print ord('1'^'3');"`

Comment: see `perldoc feature` for more information

Comment: according to `perldoc perlop` the bitwise feature, ( which is enabled with the -E flag to perl was added in Perl 5.22. We see in 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_5_version_history that
5.22. was released June 1, 2015
so I'm think some of the other examples don't apply or operate as expected with 'modern' perls.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems here:

- `$c1` and `$c2` are undefined at the start.
- They're strings.

(I'll assume there's a bit missing, such that 'c1' and 'c2' get extracted as first/last element of the list, 1 and 3 respectively)

Try:

```
$list="1 2 3";
@arr=split(" ",$list);
$c=int($arr[0])^int($arr[2]);
print "$c";
```

the `int` function explicitly casts to a numeric value.

Answer (score 1):

Perl v5.26 has a feature to [force numeric context on the bitwise operators](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2015/07/make-bitwise-operators-always-use-numeric-context/):

```
use v5.26;
use feature qw(bitwise);

my $list = "1 3";
my @arr  = split " ", $list;
my $c    = $arr[0] ^ $arr[1];
print $c, "\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

Over time, perl has changed/improved it's handling of bitwise string operations.

The answer is not simple, and there are numeric, and bitwise xor operations in perl.
I'll refer you to the [Bitwise-String-Operators](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Bitwise-String-Operators) section of the manual.  Note how they are now trying to address this "unpredictable behavior" by using the "bitwise" feature, new/experimental in Perl 5.22, stable in Perl 5.28 ( see brian d foy's article [Make bitwise operators always use numeric context](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2015/07/make-bitwise-operators-always-use-numeric-context/) that he mentions in the comments below ) .

Comment: This feature is stable in Perl v5.26: https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2015/07/make-bitwise-operators-always-use-numeric-context/

Comment: Great article Brian -